# Discord.js - limiting slash-commands to a permission

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a purge command, and I cannot figure out, how to limit the usage to users that have the MANAGE_MESSAGES permission.

I am providing the source code for the client.on("ready") part and also the entire command.

Really clueless about this one, thanks for any help.

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
  try {
    const command = await client.application.commands.create({
      name: 'purge',
      PermissionFlagsBits: 'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
      description: 'Deletes messages',
      options: [
        {
          name: 'amount',
          description: 'The amount of messages to delete',
          type: 4,
          required: true,
        },
      ],
      

      defaultPermission: false,
    });
    console.log(`Registered ${command.name} command`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});


  client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'purge') {
      const amount = interaction.options.getInteger('amount');
      if (amount > 100) {
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'You can only delete 100 messages at a time!', ephemeral: true });
      }
      if (amount < 1) {
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'You must delete at least 1 message!', ephemeral: true });
      }
      await interaction.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(error => { 
        console.error(error);
        interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error trying to delete messages in this channel!', ephemeral: true });
      });
      interaction.reply({ content: `Successfully deleted ${amount} messages!`, ephemeral: true });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in Discord.js v14. Using `PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages` returns the correct permissions for managing messages. Also, the property is `default_member_permissions`, not `PermissionFlagsBits`.

```
import { PermissionFlagsBits } from 'discord.js';

client.on('ready', async () => {
    try {
        const command = await this.application.commands.create({
            name: 'purge',
            default_member_permissions: PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages,
            description: 'Deletes messages',
            options: [
                  {
                    name: 'amount',
                    description: 'The amount of messages to delete',
                    type: 4,
                    required: true,
                  },
                ],
             defaultPermission: false,
       });

        console.log(`Registered ${command.name} command`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```